# Add words referenced in a cell to the end of a new word in a separate cell

Tags: vba, excel

Alright for this project I am trying to take columns headers and combine them in row headers in one column. For instance

There a column header plant store it has rows with corresponding data tr1, tr2, tr3.

I want to make one full column with the data so it appears like this "plant store tr1", "Plant store tr2" etc...

this is the code I have so far.

J represents an arbitrary range that I want all the data to fill

X represents the location of all the tr1, tr2s, I want added to the end of plant store

plant store is located at J15 in detailed ratings.

```
  Sub Double_column_method()

Dim J As Variant
Dim x As Variant

Set J = Range("A6:A400")
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A6").Select
For x = Sheets("Detailed Ratings").Range("J15") To Sheets("Detailed Ratings").Range("BQ15")
If J.Value <> "" Then J.Value = x&(Sheets("Detailed Ratings")).Range("I16")
Next

End Sub
```

Thank you any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Sub test()

Row = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
r = Row - 15
Column = Cells(16, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
c = Column - 9
For i = 1 To r
   For J = 1 To c
     n = n + 1
     Cells(n, "BU") = Cells(i + 15, "I") & Cells(15, J + 9)
     Next J
Next i
```

This solved it for me, produced a clean list of all my headings combined.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your post correctly, I think the following is what you need.  It can be done without VBA.  Type the formula in yellow and copy down/across.
[image: Chart1]

[image: Chart2]

Comment: I cant add a picture not enough rep but that's not what I'm trying imagine plant store in a2, tr1 in B1, tr2 in B2. So on and so forth